# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert from VB.Net to C# to read data from sql database. The following code gives me an error.*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'"*. It works perfectly fine in VB. How can I convert this statement to C#?

```
chkNewEmployee.Checked = dr["chkNewEmployee"].ToString();
```

Comment: What is the underlying database type?  Bit?  Char?

Comment: Its an straight forward conversion.Convert.use Convert.ToBoolean(dr["chkNewEmployee"])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chkNewEmployee.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["chkNewEmployee"]);
```

[ToBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd.aspx):

> **true** or **false**, which reflects the value returned by invoking the
>   IConvertible.ToBoolean method for the underlying type of value. **If
>   value is null, the method returns false.**

Depending on your needs you may want to try `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse`

**UPDATE**

[`bool.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`bool.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- are case insensitive
- ignore leading and trailing white space

[`bool.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- correct *value* is either `true` or `false`
- throws `FormatException` in case of failed conversion

[`bool.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- correct *value* is either `true` or `false`
- doesn't throw exception in case of failed conversion
- return `true` if conversion succeeded, otherwise `false`
- conversion result is saved via second parameter (`out bool result`)

[`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- correct *value* is `true`, `false` or `null` (returning `false` in case of `null`)
- throws `FormatException` in case of failed conversion

Comment: @walkhard What is the difference if i use either of the three methods?
`Convert.ToBoolean` or `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse`

Comment: @indago I've updated my answer, it should clarify the differences.

Comment: What if I have a string `string c = ddlMyNames.SelectedValue` and I am doing the following: `" + (c == "All" || c == "") ? "[ClientText] LIKE '%'" : "[ClientText] = '" + c + "'";`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I'm not sure if I follow you. Can you create new question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the segment of code below. See if it works. It should return an exception if not.

```
 try {
  chkNewEmployee.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["chkNewEmployee"]);
 }   
 catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("Bad Format");
  }   
  catch (InvalidCastException) {
   Console.WriteLine("No Conversion");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do that:

```
chkNewEmployee.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["chkNewEmployee"]);
```

and it's done.